# In a map operation, how do I filter out a specific record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a record, that when I return an association of an association, it sends me back a collection that also includes the record for the initial association. How do I filter out the original record? I know it sounds confusing, but the code below should be self-explanatory.

Basically I have a record `d`, and when the final results come back from this query - `d.parents.flat_map(&:children).uniq` I don't want it to include the record to which `d` references. How do I do that in a Ruby-esque way? It would be PERFECT if there were a Rails or Ruby built-in method that does this, so I can just chain it elegantly to my existing query but I doubt that may be the case...I am hopeful though...so extra points if you can provide that.

```
[91] pry(main)> d
=> #<User id: 2, email: "def@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$Bne..", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, gender: 0>
[92] pry(main)> d.parents
=> [#<User id: 1, email: "abc@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, gender: 0>,
 #<User id: 4, email: "jkl@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, gender: 1>]
[94] pry(main)> d.parents.flat_map(&:children).uniq
=> [#<User id: 2, email: "def@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, gender: 0>,
 #<User id: 3, email: "ghi@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, gender: 1>,
 #<User id: 5, email: "mno@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$.mXgmN...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, gender: 1>]
```

**Edit 1**

This is the structure of my associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :gender

  has_one :family_tree
  has_many :nodes
  has_many :relationships

  has_many :parent_child_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: :child_id
  has_many :parents, through: :parent_child_relationships, source: :parent

  has_many :child_parent_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: :parent_id      
  has_many :children, through: :child_parent_relationships, source: :child

  enum gender: [ :male, :female ]

  def has_children?
    !children.empty?
  end

  def has_parents?
    !parents.empty?
  end

end
```

This is my `Relationship.rb` model:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :child, class_name: "User"

  attr_accessible :parent_id, :child_id
end
```

Comment: I think you want to fetch the siblings of a user. Check out my answer. It offers a faster alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I'll delete mine because it's not needed IMHO - Humza's got this well in hand. I would suggest updating your title to match the question so it helps people searching here; perhaps something with keywords parent, child, siblings, activerecord, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d.parents.flat_map(&:children).uniq.reject{ |c| c == d }
```

or

```
d.parents.flat_map(&:children).uniq - [d]
```

But I think you're trying to get the siblings of a User. If you've got a model setup, then you should do the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parents # with keys and class_name pointing to the same class
  has_many :children # with keys and class_name pointing to the same class

  has_many :parents_children, through: :parents, source: :children

  def siblings
    self.parents_children.where("users.id != ?", self.id)
  end
end

d.siblings # what you want
```

I couldn't figure out a way to pass the `users.id != self.id` condition to a `has_many` relationship, otherwise `has_many :siblings, options` would be ideal.

Comment: I really like this approach, and this is precisely what I was looking for actually. Do you think this is better than doing the `ruby` query that I was doing before? i.e. more performant?

Comment: Yup. This would be more efficient. Apart from the Ruby filtering, you were previously querying the database once for each parent. This way, you'll be querying the database only once. And you won't be getting duplicate children.

Comment: I just updated the question with moar details on my associations - specifically that I am doing my `parent` and `child` relationships through another model - `Relationships`. How would I apply your answer, given this structure? I doubt your `has_many :parents_children...` will work...no?

Comment: It should work. You still have `has_many :parents` and `has_many :children` that are returning `users` as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#select()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-select) to filter elements from an Array in Ruby.

Example:

```
> a = [1,2,3]
> a.select{|x| not x.even?}.map{|x| x**2}
=> [1, 9]
```

In your case the select clause would just omit any records that equal `d`

Comment: Can you rewrite my original `flat_map` to include `select` or would it just be at the end like joel suggests?

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to adapt on your own.